# Peroxyacetic Acid availability

Tags: sanitation, cleaning, sanitizer

*tl;dr
Do you know where to buy, food contact PAA in packaging ≤5kg and concentration ≤5% ?*

I was going to buy Peroxyacetic Acid that already have long history of use has been approved by EU, but it is next to unavailable in UK's professional online shops.

Not many shop sells PAA that supposed to be used for food contact surfaces. But finding one smaller than 25kg is impossible! I would need only 500g or ml, considering the dilution., but I could live with anything up to 5kg
Then again only availability of small containers is with sellers not providing info that them products can be used with food contact surfaces.

I need specifically this product, for it's proven no rinse application and being food contact authorized.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this in less than 25L containers.

This is widely used in professional breweries, we buy it in 30kg containers from Murphy & Son.

- https://www.murphyandson.co.uk/product/peracetic-acid-5-30kg-hz/

NicheSolutions also carry it in 25L tubs - Percid 5 25L

- http://www.nichesolutionsgb.co.uk/food-beverage/

If you are using PAA use it at a 3% dilution, 3 parts to 100 parts water, always add chemical to water and never water to the chemical. If you are using this make sure you are using proper PPE: coveralls, gloves and goggles it is pretty vicious stuff and will burn exposed skin and destory your eyes. Make sure you read the SDS - Saftey Data Sheet and have somewhere secure to store it.

Also, you may not be able to purchase this as an individual.

Comment: I have found it on eBay actually later on but decided not to use it as it requires plenty of controls to be in place to use it in safe manner: air control, enclosed space etc.

Comment: It is highly effective, but use it incorrectly and it is very dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you're located, but speaking as a professional brewer, I'm willing to bet if you asked your local brewery (especially one you frequent!) for a pint Mason jar of peracetic and offered to pay for it, we'd be more than happy to help out.

Bring your own pint jar :)